# how to include a ":" as a parameter in powershell?

Tags: scripting, powershell-2.0, sqlcmd

i have a simple powershell script, like this

```
sqlcmd -S. -E -Q 'select ''$(x)''' -v x="c:a"
```

but i always got the error message

```
Sqlcmd: ':a': Invalid argument. Enter '-?' for help.
```

i figured out that it is the `":"` in the argument caused the problem, but i do not know how to escape it.

thanks,
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sorry that i have to answer to my own question again.

the only way to solve this problem is to use '+' to concatenate the two string, and the ':' will be reserved.

e.g. $a="abc"+":123"

Answer (score 0):

You could also alternatively try this approach that we used for scripting xdt:Transforms.

`$xmlSection.SetAttribute("xdtTransform","Insert")`

followed by

`foreach-object {$_ -replace "xdtTransform" , "xdt:Transform"}`

Answer (score -1):

<s>The backquote character is the escape code in PowerShell.  So write ``:` ....</s>

oops... That won't work for the colon character.  Use `%3A` instead.

Comment: and it will display '%3a' exactly for me? no, i want the sql script display 'c:a' for me.

Comment: i found out it is not a sqlcmd issue, it is the powershell did something with the ":" and did not pass it to sqlcmd. i executed the script in cmd.exe, and it works fine.