# sqlcmd. How to pass in a variable that includes a colon and a space?

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd

I've been struggling with this for a while now. I'm trying to invoke a sql script and pass two variables into it using sqlcmd. I'm doing all this in PowerShell.

Here's what I've got:

```
$time = '12:00 AM'
$date = '06/20/2014'
$result = sqlcmd -U username -P password -i "c:\path\to\script.sql" -v date=$date -v time=$time
```

This fails with the following error message:

```
sqlcmd : Sqlcmd: 'time=12:00 AM': Invalid argument. Enter -? for help.
```

After some experimentation, I've discovered that the problem is the colon and the space in $time. If I remove the colon and the space `$time = '1200AM'`, the command executes without any error.

Unfortunately, the script that I'm executing wants the exact format "12:00 AM".

Things that I've tried that didn't work:

```
$time="12\:00\ AM"
$time="12\\:00\\ AM"
$time="12"+":00"+" AM"
$time="12"+":00"
$time="12"+":"+"00"
```

These all respond with similar `Invalid argument` failures. The last few attempts were the solution from [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130376/how-to-include-a-as-a-parameter-in-powershell). They don't work.

I have also tried placing the string values directly in the sqlcmd invocation, like so:

```
$result = sqlcmd -U username -P password -i "c:\path\to\script.sql" -v date=$date -v time="12\:00\ AM".
```

No dice, and anyways, I need to read the time in from somewhere else, so I need the $time variable.

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041145/escaping-special-symbols-in-sqlcmd. Think you need to double up the percents. Other characters have different [escapes](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php).

Comment: @Matt Hey, I appreciate the effort, but that doesn't appear to be related. The colon and the space do not need to be escaped, at least for normal batch files. [Here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) is a list of characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: Ok... we linked the same article. and yes it would appear there is no reference to colon. My bad. What about  `-v "date=""$date"""` That should allow the time to have quotes when it gets passed to sqlcmd?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing path to SqlCmd within powershell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734529/passing-path-to-sqlcmd-within-powershell-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I figured a solution out. Hopefully it will be useful to other people somewhere down the road.

I switched from sqlcmd to Powershell's Invoke-Sqlcmd. This STILL gave me problems, so I had to fiddle around with it a little. Here's my end result.

```
# import Invoke-Sqlcmd
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100

$time = "12:01 AM"
$date = "07/22/2014"
$datetime = "time='$time'", "date='$date'" # save to $datetime as an array
$result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Username username -Password password -InputFile "c:\path\to\sql\script.sql" -Variable $datetime
```

Note that the following DOES NOT WORK:

```
$datetime = "time='"+$time+"'", "date='"+$date+"'"
```

This was the first thing I tried, and it resulted in an invalid argument exception.

Answer (score 5):

I (finally) found a solution that worked for sqlcmd from a Powershell script. (Using invoke-sqlcmd was not an option for me)

I needed to pass an absolute path containing a colon in a variable (e.g., C:\rootdir\subdir).  This worked from a regular command prompt, but I couldn't get it to work from a Powershell script.  I came up with an ugly kludge, passing the parts before and after the colon in two variables, then reassembling it in the SQL script.

But then it failed when the path contained a space (e.g., C:\root dir\subdir).

So I finally found a solution that fixed both colons and spaces.  It involved enclosing the path text in double quotes, then enclosing the double-quoted path text in an outer set of single quotes.  After building the full sqlcmd in a variable, it looked something like this:

```
SQLCMD <other args>  -v RootPath='"C:\root dir\subdir"'
```

(That's an outer set of single quotes (') and an inner set of double quotes (")).

This also worked if the path didn't have a colon, e.g., \\nodename\root dir\subdir. This had been a problem when I tried to split the path around an assumed colon.  I'm still not sure why both outer single quotes and inner double quotes are necessary, but that was the only version that worked for me.

ADDENDUM: This only worked for Powershell 5, and broke when my script was run from Powershell 4.  To make it work on both, I found I needed to enclose internal spaces in single quotes, e.g.,

```
SQLCMD <other args>  -v RootPath='"C:\root' 'dir\subdir"'
```

Answer (score 4):

I slightly modified your PowerShell script by adding spaces before and after each variable assignment operator like this:

```
$time = '12:00 AM'
$date = '06/20/2014'
$result = sqlcmd -U username -P password -i "c:\path\to\script.sql" -v date = $date -v time = $time
```

It works for me (tested on PowerShell 2.0).

Comment: Seems like parenthesis work too: `$result = sqlcmd -U username -P password -i "c:\path\to\script.sql" -v date=($date) -v time=($time)`

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try `-v "date=$date" -v "time=$time"`.

If that didn't work, I'd try this:

```
$time = '12:00 AM'
$date = '06/20/2014'
$time = 'time=' + $time
$date = 'date=' + $date
$result = sqlcmd -U username -P password -i "c:\path\to\script.sql" -v $date -v $time
```

When PowerShell executes a program, it parses the line, resolves any PowerShell in it, and then tries to execute the string.  It ends up feeling like you need an extra layer of abstraction that you don't really see in traditional shell scripts or batch scripts.

Comment: Unfortunately, these did not work. Thanks for the suggestion, though. This is a real brain-twister that I have here. I've tried Invoke-Sqlcmd, and it's giving me nearly the same problem!

Comment: @Benjamin Hm.  What about like `$time = 'time="' + $time + '"'`?  Usually what I do is put a `Write-Output` at the beginning of the line to see what the command line actually looks like, then try working backwards from there to make the string come out right.  I mean, when you run the command from `cmd.exe`, what does it look like to run correctly?  If you want to use `Invoke-Sqlcmd`, double check [the syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx) for passing variables.

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work. Same error. Using Write-Output was kind of useful because it showed me that my command was formatted the way I wanted. Sqlcmd still didn't accept it, though. In the end, I figured out a way to do it using Invoke-Sqlcmd. I gave the solution on this page.